# Attributes form: autofill in any position

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

With QGIS autofill I can easily find a value by typing its initial characters. Can I configure the field so that I can type middle characters and still find it?

[image: first letters]

[image: middle letters]

Comment: I don't think there is an easy solution for QGIS itself at the moment. However there are other data collection/entry solutions with more advanced forms such as ROAM (Windows), QField (Android) and Input (iOS, Android) which allow auto complete from the middle of a string. (Not 100% sure about Input but I know the other two do)